# Mathematical possibility/impossibility of certain Event Relationships

Tags: probability

So in a multiple choice question, about which of a series of statements about certain relationships between $A$ and $B$ are "Correct", the following answers were not the right ones, implying that they may not necessarily be true. Can anyone provide me with a proof by counter-example of how either of the following 2 statements could possibly be untrue? They are

a. $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)\cdot P(B)$ for any events $A$ and $B$
b. $P(A\cup B)\geq P(A)+P(B) $

Comment: Consider the case where $A=B$, adding that $P(A)\in(0,1)$ the first statement is not true. The second case holds assuming $P(A)\in(0,1]$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that they may be true?

Comment: Thank you. But, for "a" wouldn't the "or equal to" provision, cause the statement to still be true, even if A=B?

Comment: @Stubborn Atom:  Intuitively, they look like they should be true as in the case of the case of A:  the product of A and B since they are less than 1, should be the same size or smaller if independent. But if not independent, it's difficult for me to think of circumstances in which the probability the product might be greater.For B, I cannot conceive of how B could be untrue.

Answer (score 0):

For the first statement, suppose $A\subset B$, Then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$

Now $P(B)\leq1\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)\geq P(A).P(B)$

For the second statement, let us assume that $A\cap B\neq\phi\Rightarrow P(A\cap B)>0$

Now $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\Rightarrow P(A\cup B)<P(A)+P(B)$